# Cannot see Java Maven Tomcat-plugin web application in web browser

Tags: java, maven, docker, containers, maven-tomcat-plugin

I want to build and run my Java Maven web app in a docker container. I tried with a following command:

```
 docker run -it --name my_project -v "$PWD":/usr/src/my_project -w /usr/src/my_project maven:3.5.0-jdk-8 mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

It correctly copies the resources, run maven clean install (successful build) and run with tomcat7-maven-plugin that is included in my pom.xml.

Everything works fine and logs are really similar to build and run locally on my windows machine:

[image: Run info]

Unfortunately on a web browser there is information "connection refused".

What could potentially cause the problem?:
- my application is windows specific and cannot run on linux?
- app is fully app and running but something wrong is with proxy configuration or port is not configured?

How can i proceed further - investigate the logs? Try to build on windows docker container?

P.S. I check IP of a container with Kitematic app for windows docker.

Comment: Anything changes if you add `-p 9998:9998` parameter to the `docker run` command?

Comment: @mgyongyosi 10 points for Gryfiindor. Now access url is avaiable and visible. I'm one step further - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly three issues. Once your used `-w` instead of `-v`

```
 docker run -it --name my_project -v "$PWD":/usr/src/my_project -w /usr/src/my_project maven:3.5.0-jdk-8 mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

Which I assumed was a Typo while posting. Next you didn't publish the port on your machine

```
 docker run -p 9998:9998 -it --name my_project -v "$PWD":/usr/src/my_project -w /usr/src/my_project maven:3.5.0-jdk-8 mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

This would map the port `9998` (right side) from your container to the port `9998` on your localhost.

Third and last one, your INFO log says listening on `localhost:9998`. This is not good. Because that means your war is listening from traffic generated inside the the container only and not from outside the container. You need to configure your war so it listens on all interfaces inside the container and bind should be `0.0.0.0:9998`

Comment: What do you mean by "traffic generated inside the container only"? I would like the app to be builded locally with docekr, but actually it should have access to local Windows files (outside the container). Should I add anything to the container or configure something?

Comment: Listening to localhost means you listen to whatever the localhost context is. Inside a VM it is a the VM, Inside the container it the container itself. So if your a in a terminal with bash inside your VM or container then localhost would point to that. Also a app listening to localhost is only going to respond to the request raised from that context. That's why you always need to listen to `0.0.0.0`. About need the file system you would need to use a volume mount. Look at the `--volume` or `-v` flag of a docker run command